# Create a List-type view dynamically from a Json object in MVC3

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, view

I have a controller that access a WCF service which returns a Json object (collection). All rows are of same type, but at different calls the row stricture is different (the return object comes from a user-built sql query, executed with executeReader and serialized as Json
So I don't know the row structure upfront.

What I need is an easy way to pass this Json string to something which will generate a view of type list on the fly for it. Doesn't matter formatting, etc, just should be output easily as a table.

Does anyone knows how can I accomplish this?

Another option might be to have something that generate  the view on the fly for a IEnumerable of anonymous objects (since using [this](http://www.drowningintechnicaldebt.com/ShawnWeisfeld/archive/2010/08/22/using-c-4.0-and-dynamic-to-parse-json.aspx) I could convert the json to a list of anonymous)

---

EDIT

I found something that does pretty much what I need, except it display metadata about passed object.

It is [preetyPrint.js](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/prettyprint-for-javascript/), and I integrated it in my page as below:
In my controller I set the result json object to ViewBag.Result, and in the view I used this code:

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/prettyprint.js")" type="text/javascript">    </script>
    <div id="resultGrid"></div>
    <script>
    var resultObject = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Result);            
    var ppTable = prettyPrint(resultObject);
    document.getElementById('resultGrid').appendChild(ppTable);         
    </script>
```

Does anyone knows such script that actually "dump" the data instead of metadata?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a class to deserialize to if you know the properties of the row.  Then use the `JavaScriptSerializer` class to deserialize to a list of your new class you created.  Then you can take a look at the [`WebGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgrid%28v=vs.99%29.aspx) class to output the HTML, or just manually iterate over the property metadata in your view.

Creating a custom class will provide you the ability to use metadata to control formatting or other display attributes of the output.

If you cannot create a custom class, you can always use Json.NET or the `JavaScriptSerializer` to deserialize to a list of dictionary objects or `ExpandoObject` / `Dynamic`'s or something.  Then you would have to manually write something to iterate the keys I think.  The `ModelMetadataProvider` in MVC may be able to handle these allowing you to just iterate the properties in your view code.